# expected scalar type Byte but found Float

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

This is the format of data that I am using
I tried to transform it to byte tensor using x =x.byte() but had no effect at all
the data are  300 x500 pictures   transformation I am using is only NumPy to tensor
my dataset  is  created using this tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html

```
tensor([[[[164, 164, 164,  ..., 178, 178, 178],
          [164, 164, 164,  ..., 178, 178, 178],
          [164, 164, 164,  ..., 178, 178, 178],
          ...,
          [169, 169, 169,  ..., 176, 176, 176],
          [169, 169, 169,  ..., 176, 176, 176],
          [169, 169, 169,  ..., 176, 176, 176]],

         [[164, 164, 164,  ..., 171, 171, 171],
          [164, 164, 164,  ..., 171, 171, 171],
          [164, 164, 164,  ..., 171, 171, 171],
          ...,
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 169, 169, 169],
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 169, 169, 169],
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 169, 169, 169]],

         [[152, 152, 152,  ..., 163, 163, 163],
          [152, 152, 152,  ..., 163, 163, 163],
          [152, 152, 152,  ..., 163, 163, 163],
          ...,
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 153, 153, 153],
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 153, 153, 153],
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 153, 153, 153]]],


        [[[ 44,  44,  44,  ...,  45,  45,  45],
          [ 44,  44,  44,  ...,  45,  45,  45],
          [ 44,  44,  44,  ...,  45,  45,  45],
          ...,
          [127, 127, 127,  ...,  58,  58,  58],
          [127, 127, 127,  ...,  58,  58,  58],
          [127, 127, 127,  ...,  58,  58,  58]],

         [[ 50,  50,  50,  ...,  40,  40,  40],
          [ 50,  50,  50,  ...,  40,  40,  40],
          [ 50,  50,  50,  ...,  40,  40,  40],
          ...,
          [128, 128, 128,  ...,  47,  47,  47],
          [128, 128, 128,  ...,  47,  47,  47],
          [128, 128, 128,  ...,  47,  47,  47]],

         [[ 62,  62,  62,  ...,  60,  60,  60],
          [ 62,  62,  62,  ...,  60,  60,  60],
          [ 62,  62,  62,  ...,  60,  60,  60],
          ...,
          [132, 132, 132,  ...,  41,  41,  41],
          [132, 132, 132,  ...,  41,  41,  41],
          [132, 132, 132,  ...,  41,  41,  41]]],


        [[[ 39,  39,  39,  ...,  41,  41,  41],
          [ 39,  39,  39,  ...,  41,  41,  41],
          [ 39,  39,  39,  ...,  41,  41,  41],
          ...,
          [ 36,  36,  36,  ...,  36,  36,  36],
          [ 36,  36,  36,  ...,  36,  36,  36],
          [ 36,  36,  36,  ...,  36,  36,  36]],

         [[ 26,  26,  26,  ...,  21,  21,  21],
          [ 26,  26,  26,  ...,  21,  21,  21],
          [ 26,  26,  26,  ...,  21,  21,  21],
          ...,
          [ 28,  28,  28,  ...,  21,  21,  21],
          [ 28,  28,  28,  ...,  21,  21,  21],
          [ 28,  28,  28,  ...,  21,  21,  21]],

         [[ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  22,  22,  22],
          [ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  22,  22,  22],
          [ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  22,  22,  22],
          ...,
          [ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  18,  18,  18],
          [ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  18,  18,  18],
          [ 17,  17,  17,  ...,  18,  18,  18]]],


        ...,


        [[[169, 169, 169,  ..., 169, 169, 169],
          [169, 169, 169,  ..., 169, 169, 169],
          [169, 169, 169,  ..., 169, 169, 169],
          ...,
          [167, 167, 167,  ..., 180, 180, 180],
          [167, 167, 167,  ..., 180, 180, 180],
          [167, 167, 167,  ..., 180, 180, 180]],

         [[171, 171, 171,  ..., 166, 166, 166],
          [171, 171, 171,  ..., 166, 166, 166],
          [171, 171, 171,  ..., 166, 166, 166],
          ...,
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 173, 173, 173],
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 173, 173, 173],
          [163, 163, 163,  ..., 173, 173, 173]],

         [[158, 158, 158,  ..., 161, 161, 161],
          [158, 158, 158,  ..., 161, 161, 161],
          [158, 158, 158,  ..., 161, 161, 161],
          ...,
          [151, 151, 151,  ..., 165, 165, 165],
          [151, 151, 151,  ..., 165, 165, 165],
          [151, 151, 151,  ..., 165, 165, 165]]],


        [[[ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  50,  50,  50],
          [ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  50,  50,  50],
          [ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  50,  50,  50],
          ...,
          [ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  59,  59,  59],
          [ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  59,  59,  59],
          [ 57,  57,  57,  ...,  59,  59,  59]],

         [[ 48,  48,  48,  ...,  37,  37,  37],
          [ 48,  48,  48,  ...,  37,  37,  37],
          [ 48,  48,  48,  ...,  37,  37,  37],
          ...,
          [ 43,  43,  43,  ...,  39,  39,  39],
          [ 43,  43,  43,  ...,  39,  39,  39],
          [ 43,  43,  43,  ...,  39,  39,  39]],

         [[ 33,  33,  33,  ...,  31,  31,  31],
          [ 33,  33,  33,  ...,  31,  31,  31],
          [ 33,  33,  33,  ...,  31,  31,  31],
          ...,
          [ 30,  30,  30,  ...,  30,  30,  30],
          [ 30,  30,  30,  ...,  30,  30,  30],
          [ 30,  30,  30,  ...,  30,  30,  30]]],


        [[[136, 136, 136,  ..., 132, 132, 132],
          [136, 136, 136,  ..., 132, 132, 132],
          [136, 136, 136,  ..., 132, 132, 132],
          ...,
          [141, 141, 141,  ..., 203, 203, 203],
          [141, 141, 141,  ..., 203, 203, 203],
          [141, 141, 141,  ..., 203, 203, 203]],

         [[140, 140, 140,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          [140, 140, 140,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          [140, 140, 140,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          ...,
          [144, 144, 144,  ..., 209, 209, 209],
          [144, 144, 144,  ..., 209, 209, 209],
          [144, 144, 144,  ..., 209, 209, 209]],

         [[143, 143, 143,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          [143, 143, 143,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          [143, 143, 143,  ..., 138, 138, 138],
          ...,
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 209, 209, 209],
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 209, 209, 209],
          [149, 149, 149,  ..., 209, 209, 209]]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import torch


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 300, 535)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(3, 300, 535)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)


    def forward(self, x):
       
        print(x)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

```
expected scalar type Byte but found Float
  File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\cs_agent\cs_agent\neural_network.py", line 20, in forward
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
  File "C:\Users\david\Desktop\cs_agent\cs_agent\main.py", line 66, in <module>
    outputs = net(inputs)
```

Comment: Is you kernel size 535 in `Conv2d` layers? Because, it is too big.

Comment: It seem to be to big can you help me to find the right shape @TheExile

Comment: Arguments of `Conv2d` are `torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros', device=None, dtype=None)`, refer to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html). So, the first argument is number of channels of your images. `1` for grayscale, `3` RGB images. The second argument is how many filters you want to learn in this layer, i.e., output channels. The third argument is kernel size which is usually `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`... Also, `Conv2d` supports `TensorFloat32`, not `Byte`.

Comment: I have updated the `Conv2d ` function to look like this  `self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d( 3, 300,kernel_size=1,stride=1, padding=0)`  but now I run into this error again ` return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float` @TheExile first issue was definitely the size of tensor

Comment: Your input is type of `Byte`, you need to convert it to `float` before giving into `forward` function, like, `net(x.float())`

Comment: Thank you that fixed the issue  now I only need to arrange the linear layers @TheExile